# Find longest ascending number sequence in a string

Tags: java

The program is supposed to give the longest ascending order.

So, for example, if I input "12134707" it should give output = 1347 however it's giving 12... which is definitely not the longest. what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;        
public class Ascending
{

public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.print("Enter a number = ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n = in.nextLine();

    //print soluton
    System.out.println("output = " + itsAscending(n));
}

public static String itsAscending(String n) {
    int length = n.length(); 

    String maxlongest = "";


    for(int i = 1; i < length; i++) {

        char first = n.charAt(i-1); 
        char second = n.charAt(i);      
        char next = n.charAt(i+1);
        int f = (int)(first - 48);      
        int s = (int)(second - 48);     
        int nx = (int)(next - 48);

        String longest = "";

        int max = 0;


        //test to find the ascending order
        if (f<s){

            longest = longest + f;

            if(n.length()>2){

                if(f<s){
                    longest = longest + s;
                    length = longest.length();
                    i++;
                }
                else{
                    i++; 
                    continue;
                }
            }

            //test to find the longest string
            for (i=1; i<length; i++){
                if (length > max){
                    max = length;
                    maxlongest = longest;
                    return maxlongest;
                }
                else {
                    return maxlongest;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxlongest;
 }
}
```

Comment: is it not a homework problem?

Comment: I suggest you to debug the code to find out what is going wrong and where.

Comment: @Anubhab does that matter? It seems to me he's put effort in it and can't find the one thing that goes wrong. So why wouldn't he be asking it here?

Comment: @Joetjah obviously he can..can you please tell me why then some people reject questions saying its a homework prob?

Comment: @Anubhab It used to be a thing on SO to have questions regarding homework tagged as such and people got quite bitchy about people not tagging their questions properly. However, the use of the tag "homework" is discouraged by now (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)).

Comment: Because people like to ask those questions in the form of: "I need to do this, insert that and get the modified value. How should I do this?". They don't show effort.

Comment: @Joetjah This question doesn't look like "no effort" to me. Not at all.

Comment: okok..got it now..i wan confused about this concept.. :)

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig That's what I thought as well.

Comment: @user2181267 Nishant Shreshth is right, try debugging through placing some `Debug.Log(...)` lines, and set breakpoints on the correct places. Value-watch some variables so you know how the variables change throughout the loops. You might find out what's going wrong there.

Comment: @user2181267 Does this have to work for characters as well or only for digits?

Comment: yes, this is a homework problem. and yes only for digits please! I'm also not exactly sure how to use either the Debug.Log... or how to debug the code... this is for an intro Java class

Comment: @user2181267 why you are checking if(f<s) condition inside if(f<s) again?

Comment: Removed homework tag. @MohammadFaisal Please don't use it or add it to questions.

Comment: @Dukeling: I don't understand why you have removed the `homework` tag?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Because the homework [has been deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

Hey u are messing up the code & logic at many places. You are comparing with length variable in for loop and modifying it. Also your second for loop is inside the 1st one. I think its a mistake. Start fresh go through your logic & variables again.. Your length variable & i variable are used at multiple places where instead a coy of the same should be used.

P.S: I know its a HW assignment :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you make your code simpler by splitting functionality into different functions:

Parse the string:

```
public static int[] parseString(String str) {
    int[] result = new int[str.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (int)(str.charAt(i) - 48);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Solve the problem:

```
public static String solve(String str) {
    int[] a = parseString(str);
    int length = 1;
    int maxStart = 0;
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; a++) {
        if (a[i] <= a[i-1]) {
            if (length < (start - i)) {
                length = start - i;
                maxStart = start;
            }
            start = i;
        }
    }
    return str.substring(maxStart, maxStart+length);
}
```

This will only work for non-empty strings, but I assume you can fix that yourself...

Answer (score 0):

in second loop:

```
    //test to find the longest string
    for (i=1; i<length; i++){
        if (length > max){
            max = length;
            maxlongest = longest;
            return maxlongest;
        }
        else {
            return maxlongest;
        }
    }`
```

either `if` will execute or `else` will execute but in both cases it will `return`.
so your second `for` loop will not execute more than once and will also cause to terminate first loop.
you can remove second loop and return statements in it.
And there is no reason to check `if(f<s)` again.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ascending {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( System.in) ;
    String s = scanner.nextLine();
    String res = getAsc(s);
    System.out.println(res);

}

private static String getAsc (String n) {
    String tmp="" , org="" ;
    char cf,cs;
    int f,s ;
    for (int i=1;i < n.length(); i++) {
        cf = n.charAt(i-1);
        cs = n.charAt(i);
        f = (int) (cf - 48);
        s = (int) (cs - 48 ) ;
        if (f  < s ) {
            tmp += cf ;
        }
        else {
            tmp += cf;
            if (tmp.length() > org.length()) {
                org = tmp ;
            }
            tmp = "";
        }
    }

    return org;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using lists for making it easier keeping track of the maximum and temporary string.

```
public static String itsAscending(String n) {
    List<Integer> maxLongest = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> tempLongest = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
        int digit = (int)(n.charAt(i) - 48);             
        if (tempLongest.size() > 0 && digit < tempLongest.get(tempLongest.size() - 1)) {
            tempLongest.clear();
        }
        tempLongest.add(digit);
        if (tempLongest.size() > maxLongest.size()) {
            maxLongest.clear();
            maxLongest.addAll(tempLongest);
        }
    }
    String returnString = "";
    for (int digit : maxLongest){ 
        returnString += digit;
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: I have try your solution on this case : Enter a number = 1235461246 output = 1235 . If are multiple substrings with the same number of digits , like in the example above : 1235 and 1246 , you solution find just the first one . So your code is very good but you forget about this case IMHO or ?

Comment: Depends, the question did not explicitly state what should happen in this case. But the method _ itsAscending_ in the original question returns just a single String, not an array or list of String.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- you don't need to convert chars to ints: chars are comparable;
- you don't need to cast integer expressions to `int`;
- your "test to find the longest string" loop seems pointless: you return unconditionally in the first iteration;
- towards the bottom of the first loop you increment `i` unconditionally; that should happen outside the `if` statement;
- you have the `next` variable that you don't use anywhere;
- your `length` variable is redundant: it's just the length of the `longest` string.

Due to all these problems it is much easier to start from scratch than to try and find a single point in your code that could be changed to make it work. So here's what I got:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number = ");
    String in = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    System.out.println("output = " + longestAscending(in));
}

static String longestAscending(String in) {
    int startOfLongest = 0;
    int endOfLongest = 0;
    for (int start = 0; start < in.length();) {
        int end = start;
        for (int prevChar = -1;
             end < in.length() && in.charAt(end) > prevChar;
             prevChar = in.charAt(end), end++)
        { }
        if (end - start > endOfLongest - startOfLongest) {
            startOfLongest = start;
            endOfLongest = end;
        }
        start = end;
    }
    return in.substring(startOfLongest, endOfLongest);
}
```

Comment: Enter a number = 1235461246
output = 1235  . If are multiple substrings with the same number of digits , like in the example above : 1235 and 1246 , you solution find just the first one . So your code is very good but you forget about this case IMHO or ?

Comment: My answer meets the question, which is not "find all the shortest ascending sequences in a string".

Answer (score 0):

A little similar problem and my solution .This solution could be adapt to solve the OP solution too

the longest sequence of ascending digits in a  alphanumeric String
Coding question:

Imagine that you are at work and have been given a task to write a function that will be used in one of our products.

Part 1) In the programming language of your choice (which you should name in your answer), write a function that takes a text string as its single input and returns an integer which is the length of the longest sequence of ascending digits found in the string. Any non-digit characters terminate a sequence of digits but should otherwise be ignored.

Part 2) What test cases would you want to test your function with to demonstrate that it works correctly? Why? Give specific examples of test input strings and expected output.

For example:

If the input string is "5123a4" the output integer should be 3, because the sequence "123" is the longest sequence of ascending digits and has length 3.

If the input string is "bb54324687cc" the output integer should be 4, because the sequence "2468" is the longest sequence of ascending digits and has length 4.

package com.company;

```
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    System.out.print("Enter a number = ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("n = "+n);
    longestAscending(n);

    //n = "bb54324687cc";



}
public static Hashtable<String,Integer>longestAscending(String n) {
    Hashtable<String,Integer> h= new Hashtable<String, Integer>() ;
    String tempMax ="";
    int lenghtString=0;
    System.out.println("n.length()-1="+(n.length()-1));
    // int digit = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=n.length()-2;i++)
    {
        int homePositionDigit = (int)(n.charAt(i) - 48);
        int neighbourPositionDigit = (int)(n.charAt(i+1) - 48);

        System.out.print(" i = "+i +"  homePositionDigit ="+(n.charAt(i)-48));
        System.out.println("  neighbourPositionDigit ="+(n.charAt(i+1)-48));

        if ((homePositionDigit <=9 )&& (neighbourPositionDigit<=9))
        {
            if (n.charAt(i)<n.charAt(i+1))
            {
                tempMax=tempMax+n.charAt(i);
                lenghtString=tempMax.length();
                h.put(tempMax,lenghtString);
                System.out.println("hash table h="+h);

            }

        }
        else
        if ((homePositionDigit>9)&&(tempMax!="")&&((n.charAt(i-1)-48)<=9))
        {
            tempMax=tempMax+n.charAt(i-1);
            lenghtString=tempMax.length();
            h.put(tempMax,lenghtString);
            tempMax="";
            lenghtString=0;

        }
    }

    System.out.println("hash table h="+h);
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> it = h.entrySet().iterator();
    int kontor=0,max=0 ;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = it.next();
        if (kontor==0)
            max=entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("max este = "+max+" entry.getValue()= "+entry.getValue());


        if (entry.getValue() > max   ) {
            max=entry.getValue();
        }
        kontor++;
    }
    System.out.println("max este "+max);
    System.out.println("hash table este "+h);

    it=h.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = it.next();
        if (max==entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("the longest sequence of ascending digits in a  String is   = " + entry.getKey()+" and has the lenght of= "+max );
        }
    }
    return h;

}
```

}